# Besides mining Bitcoin what is another good use for an Antminer S1?

Tags: mining-hardware, scrypt, sha256

Are there any other SHA-256 coins out there that are worth mining? Also, would I be able to mine scrypt-based coins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many other SHA256 coins. Whether they are "worth mining" will depend on their difficulty, market value, the cost of your electricity, and the value of the time it takes you to  set them up. As all these things are constantly changing, your first question cannot really be answered in a way that will have any lasting usefulness; such questions are discouraged on Stack Exchange.

For your second question: this is an ASIC device that is capable of running SHA256 and nothing else. You cannot use it to mine scrypt coins.